# BigQuery URL issue \/\/ when perform update query using PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

```
$message='{"URL":"https:\/\/test.myscripts.com\/\/api\/\/Orders\/\/Submit"}';

UPDATE dbname.orders SET status='SUCCESS', message='{$message}', updated_at='{$updated_at}' WHERE order_id='{$order_id}';
```

Error Return As:

> Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: / at [1:95]

Comment: Use prepared statements so you don't have to worry about quoting or escaping errors. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You can use [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode) to avoid any mismatch in your URL.

Comment: Thank you @JoseGutierrezPaliza going to check from my end